# Drupal breadcrumb not showing

Tags: drupal, breadcrumbs

I have a drupal application in which I am using taxonomy breadcrumb module, it is working good in all taxonomy and term pages, however it is not showing in nodes, and especially in my homepage ( a node assigned to home page in back end node/36 ).

Any help highly appreciable

Answer (score 0):

By default, the front page has "Home" item and modules like Custom Breadcrumbs allows hiding it.
For an example, say node/35 and node/36 belongs to same contexts, but node/36 is the home page, the node/36(front page) will always has the "Home" part of the breadcrumb.
Also, if nodes are not assigned to taxonomy terms through a module, such as Forum, they will only has the Home > Node-Title breadcrumb where.
May be you are looking for Custom Breadcrumb of Menu Breadcrumb modules?